# Multisite: Redirect Subsite Administrator to Subsite Home Page, Bypassing Dashboard

Tags: multisite, redirect, login

The subsite administrators of my multisite installation want to go directly to the subsite home page upon login, bypassing the dashboard.  Irrespective of the wisdom of this, it's what they clearly want to do.

I have attempted to implement the suggestions found in the following two posts (among others) without success:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127453/redirect-after-login-on-wordpress

[Multisite - Redirect All Users to Subsite Home Page on Subsite Login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126996/multisite-redirect-all-users-to-subsite-home-page-on-subsite-login)  (including removing the "if (is_admin)" code ).

This seems like it should be straight-forward, but I am struggling. Any guidance would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`login_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) filter:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'wpse_159078_login_redirect' );
function wpse_159078_login_redirect( $redirect ) {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
        // if it's not a super admin that's logging in
        $redirect = get_home_url();
    }
    return $redirect;

}
```

#### References

- [`login_redirect` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect)
- [`get_home_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_url)